# Is it possible to adjust a 3D glTF objects' rotation parameters in the backend before sending it to the frontend?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I want to display a 3D object to the user with react-three-fiber but do not want to send the rotation parameters which are being stored in the backend as I do not want the user to see those. I just want the user to see the rotated object. Therefore I would like to know if it is possible to set the rotation parameters of the glTF object in the backend (e.g. Java spring boot) and then send the glTF object to the frontend.

I have a feeling that this will not solve the problem 100% as the user will be able to access the glTF files' content and nonetheless see the rotation parameters. Does Three.js provide something like an *encrypted GLTFLoader*?

Other solutions like rotating the camera instead are not applicable in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: The only thing on the web that uses encryption that the end user is unable to decrypt to raw data is DRM video. Everything else is obfuscated at best. You can apply the rotation to the data in the gltf , but not sure thats worth the effort.